# Arcgis Javascript API for query tasks on tiled map service

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-web-adf, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm using ArcGIS Javascript API 3.17 to view my point data from ArcGIS server 10.3. Initially I have published the point data as dynamic map service but it is taking too long time to render the data over web as my feature class has around 80,000 point features. So I've changed dynamic map service to tiled map service and generated the cache. Now it is rendering too fast from cached tiles. Now the issue is that I have to perform Query task on my data.

Is it required to add dynamic map service also under tiled service in the map to perform the query tasks?

Comment: As per the [Tour] please ask only one question per question.  Coding questions should always include a code snippet.

Comment: You've edited it but you still have three question marks indicating three questions.  I notice that you have not taken the 2-minute [Tour] where the need for one question per question is mentioned right upfront to let all users know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no. `QueryTask` has no dynamic map service requirement. you can find a sample with no map whatsoever here:
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/query_nomap.html